# square bracket before class definition in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've seen the embed tag used before the class definition, but I just saw that Keith is using these..

```
[Event(name="select", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="close", type="flash.events.Event")]
[Event(name="resize", type="flash.events.Event")]
public class Window extends Component{
```

can someone tell me what this does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most importantantly, the Flex compiler uses it when interpreting MXML. But really its just metadata, ASDocs & some code completion implementations will use it to show you the available events, but thats about it.

Its in the docs here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createevents_3.html

Hope that helps!

*(answer edited to be more accurate)*

Comment: lol ya it is, the best thing to do when searching for those it to add "metadata" to the search query.

Comment: You can make your own meta data as well if you want. E.g. you can have metadata like `[Divillysausages(someVar="value")]`. You'll need to specify `-keep-as3-metadata+=Divillysausages` in your project compiler settings, and you can access it through the `describeType()` function