# Loading XML objects from an XML List using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, list, flash-cs5

I am trying to load the description, address etc from a list when a user clicks on a name in the list!

A stack overflow member has helped me out alot with this and I thank him however I am still having problems loading the required information into text boxes! When running the following code that I have posted I get these errors

**List, Layer 'List', Frame 1, Line 36  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbracket before type.**

**List, Layer 'List', Frame 1, Line 36  1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbracket.**

I am so far but so far away please can somebody help thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the offending line was:

```
[ListEvent type="name" bubbles=false cancelable=true columnIndex=0 rowIndex=0 index=0 item=[object Object]]
```

You can safely remove it. It's simply a notation used in **classes** (not frames, like this), to signal that this class dispatches events of that type.

[This is a similar question which gives more information on the use of these lines.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629961/square-bracket-before-class-definition-in-as3)

And David, when posting a question try removing the elements that don't affect the issue and posting the entire code in the question (if it's not too big, of course). This way when someone comes from a search engine or linked by another question, they can see the code even if pastie is down.